# Unknown provider: $angularCacheFactoryProvider - angular-cache can not be found

Tags: caching

I am trying to implement angular-cache in my app. I have downloaded it and include a tag in html

However I keep getting the error: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $angularCacheFactoryProvider <- $angularCacheFactory

I'd appreciate some help

My code is the following:

controllers.js

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', ['$scope', '$angularCacheFactory', 'myService', '$http', '$rootScope', 'Util', '$location', function ($scope, $angularCacheFactory, myService, $http, $rootScope, Util, $location) {

             $rootScope.allDeals = [];

             $scope.navigate = function(url){
                 $location.path(url);
             };

             myService.getDataById(1)
                 .then(function (data) {
                     // e.g. "time taken for request: 2375ms"
                     // Data returned by this next call is already cached.
                     myService.getDataById(1)
                         .then(function (data) {
                             // e.g. "time taken for request: 1ms"
                         });
                    });

             }])
```

services.js

.service('myService',['$http', '$q', '$rootScope', '$angularCacheFactory', function ($http, $q, $rootScope, $angularCacheFactory) {

```
    $rootScope.allDeals = [];

    $angularCacheFactory('dataCache', {

        maxAge: 900000,

        // Items will be actively deleted when they expire
        deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive',


        // This cache will clear itself every hour
        cacheFlushInterval: 3600000

          });
    return {
        getDataById: function (id) {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                start = new Date().getTime();

            $http.get('http://dev.somecompany.net/bigcapi/info/info/someinfo' + id, {
                params: {all: '1', mobileready: 1},
                cache: $angularCacheFactory.get('dataCache')
            }).success(function (data) {
                $rootScope.allDeals = data;
                console.log('time taken for request: ' + (new Date().getTime() - start) + 'ms');
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
             }
         };


     }])
```

Answer (score 1):

U forgot to include angular-cache module dependency

Comment: thank you for your comment. I declared it like this:   var starter = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.services', 'jmdobry.angular-cache']) in my app.js but I get the following error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module jmdobry.angular-cache due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'jmdobry.angular-cache' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: which version of angular-cache r u using
for 2.x.x add 'jmdobry.angular-cache'
for 3.x.x add "angular-data.DSCacheFactory" (docs: http://angular-data.pseudobry.com/documentation/api/angular-cache/angular-cache)

Comment: hi, yes i was sung the wrong version, i downloaded the right one now and it's working